# Como poner un componente dentro de otro en ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, component

Necesito poner un componente dentro de otro en ReactJS...

> **Tengo un componente que se llama Fondo el cual utilizo como fondo de todas las paginas y funciona perfectamente:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Styles.css';
class Fondo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Fondo">Esto es el fondo</div> 
  );
 }
}
export default Fondo;
```

> Y otro que se llama **Monitor** (Que es un bloque div el cual quiero posicionar dentro de **Fondo**) que al ponerlo luego de  se ven los dos perfectamente... ahora, aquí viene el problema:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Styles.css';
class Monitor extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Monitor">Esto es el fondo</div>    
   );
  };
}
export default Monitor;
```

> Todo esto va dentro de una pagina llamada **Display** y **necesito que Monitor se vea dentro de Fondo**, cosa que no he logrado hasta ahora...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Fondo from '../../components/fondo';
import Monitor from '../../components/monitor';
import './Styles.css';

class Display extends Component {
    render(){
    return (
        <div>

           <Fondo > Dentro de esto </Fondo>

            <Monitor> Quiero meter esto</Monitor>

           </div>
      );
   }
}
export default Display;
```

`/* Intenté hacer esto **<Fondo> <Monitor> </Monitor> </Fondo>** pero entiendo que no es la forma indicada de hacerlo, si pueden ayudarme les agradecería mucho, se vienen cosas grandes genios!!! */`

Answer (score 1):

Si entendi bien lo que quieres hacer solo tienes que importar tu componente Monitor dentro de fondo no dentro de display... el resto del codigo se mantiene asi.. y eliminar tu `<Monitor> Quiero meter esto</Monitor>` de dentro de display..

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Styles.css';
import Monitor from '../../components/monitor'
class Fondo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Fondo">Esto es el fondo
        <Monitor />
      </div> 
  );
 }
}
export default Fondo;
```

Esto que dices que probastes tambien deberia funcionar..

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Fondo from '../../components/fondo';
import Monitor from '../../components/monitor';

class Display extends Component {
    render(){
    return (
        <div>
           <Fondo> 
            <Monitor />
           </Fondo>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
export default Display;
```

Comment: **Muchas gracias genio!** pero no es lo que buscaba, _considero que esa forma que me diste es correctisima_, solo que busco una forma mas sencilla aún... algo como el ejemplo que puse anteriormente de 
 `<Componente1> <Componente2></Componente2> </Componente1> `
ya que necesitaré poner muchos componentes dentro de otros componentes más tarde y esto es solo para que yo pueda comprender el ejemplo (soy bastante burro la verdad jaja)

Comment: esta respuesta no funciona, el componente `Fondo` no acepta  sub componentes, en este caso `Monitor`.